# Andrew and Ben play on graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Given complete graph with $n$ vertices. Andrew in his turn removes exactly one edge and Ben in his turn removes two or three edges. They take turns one after another and Andrew begins. The player loses if the graph is disconnected after his turn. For what $n$ does Ben win and what's his winning strategy? For what $n$ does Andrew win?

Thank you for any hints or solutions!

Comment: Have you tried some small cases?  Ben wins $2$, Andrew wins $3$.  What about $4$?

Comment: Right before the game ends, the graph will be a union  of disconnected [star graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)).

Comment: @SeanRoberson I don't really know any game theory lemmas/methods, thus I only tried some basic strategies - non of which led to the solution. PS. don't worry, after edit Ben is all right ;)

Comment: @RossMillikan for $4$, Ben always wins...

Comment: @vadim123, it can also be a union of disconnected paths, i.e. subgraphs of $4$ vertices connected with $3$ edges...

Comment: @AliciaS. paths cannot be since you can take out the middle edge... vadim is correct

Comment: @gt6989b I meant, that if there's only one such path, and e.g. Andrews move, then he does remove the middle edge and then the game finishes as Ben cannot commit any move.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268659207_A_game_of_edge_removal_on_graphs

Comment: Thans for extra source, @wonce. Have any of you guys came up with any idea? :)